# No nested results in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

i have a strange behavior in C# with EF
It's a .NET Core project with EF Core 1.1.0

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
```

I've created two Models, "User" and "Group"

```
 public class User
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
 }

 public class Group
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string groupName { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
 }
```

The result schould give me a User with a list of his groups.

Now the strange part:

Result comes back from DB, i look into allUser, Groups are Null

I take a look into the context to see the Groups

Groups are filled:

[image: Groups are filled]

Now i look again into allUser Result and magically 
the Group is filled inside every User item.

Groups are filled inside User:

[image: Groups are filled inside User]

I really appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you are lazy loading the entities.

You can eager load them by using `.Include`.

```
 var allUsers = context.Users.Include(user => user.Groups).ToList();
```

This approach loads the first entity (Users) as well as the related entities as part of the query (Groups).

Comment: There is no lazy loading with Entity Framework Core. LazyLoadingEnabled won't be available for instance. More infos : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data (Lazy loading is not yet possible with EF Core.)

Comment: Yes, it works with the .Include, thank you all so much!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not magic the DbContext won't download entities from the DB until you not tirgger that. When you clicked on the `context.Groups` `Results View` in debugging, the DbContext gets all the Groups from the DB so after that it can associate to the users.

I think you are searching for the Include method where you can get the users with the associated groups in one query like this:

```
var allUsers = context.Users.Include(u => u.Groups).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior comes from the laziness of loading entities.

By default, you have to manually load each of sub-entity. It is called eager-loading.

In order to eager-load your entities, you have to use the `.Include()` method on each of your navigation properties.

e.g. `context.User.Include(x => x.Groups)`

The Include method generates a new SQL statement to retrieve your Groups from database.

Then you can use the `ToList()` method to force executing your query.