# EF: Navigation property is null even after accessing it or removing virtual keyword

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to entity framework **(core)**, I am facing some problem related to **lazy loading** as I think.

I have the following simple data model with **one to one** relationship:

```
User ----- AccessToken
```

User:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual AccessToken AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

AccessToken:

```
public class AccessToken
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User"), Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I trying to get the AccessToken of a User using the User's navigation property it is always **null**:

```
var t1 = Context.Find<User>(user.Id);
var t2 = t1.AccessToken;
var t3 = Context.Find<User>(user.Id).AccessToken;
```

I also tried to remove `virtual` keyword from the navigation properties with no success.

Would some one help me to solve that problem please?

Comment: Are you using EF Core? (I see your Question is tagged EF6, but I still believe you use Core) EF Core doesn't support lazy loading yet, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42596737/455493. Please use the search, its the 2nd or 3rd question within 48 hours

Comment: @Tseng Ok so I need to use include. thanks.

Comment: ok microsoft mentioned this: `Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context instance. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a navigation property, the property may still be populated if some or all of the related entities were previously loaded.` but that is actually not happening! if I understood that correctly.

Comment: In your sample code, you never loaded `AccessToken`. They say *Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties to any other entities that were **previously loaded into the context** instance*. Your `AccessToken` were **not** previously loaded into the context, that's why it didn't work anyway.

Comment: @Alisson Could you show me how to load it?, and what does `load` exactly mean?

Comment: @Alisson, this is it, right? `Context.AccessTokens.Load();`

Comment: Yes, docs are clear on it: `context.Entry(blog).Collection(b => b.Posts).Load();` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#explicit-loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is not a 1:1 relationship. As for the database, there can be multiple `AccessToken`s with the same `UserId`, i.e. it's a 1:n relationship. To turn it into a real 1:1 relationship, your model should look like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual AccessToken AccessToken { get; set; }
}

public class AccessToken
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Now any `AccessToken` will have a PK that's identical to its `User`'s PK, so it's unique *and* tied to only one user.

Next, as said in the comments, lazy loading is not yet supported in EF core. Until it is (if ever?) you have to use `Include` (eager loading) ...

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var user = db.Users.Include(u => u.AccessToken)
                 .Single(u => u.Id == 1);
}
```

... or load the data separately (eplicit loading):

```
    db.AccessTokens.Where(a => a.Id == 1).Load();
    var user = db.Users
                 .Single(u => u.Id == 1); // Or db.Users.Find(1)
```

In the latter case, EF will connect the user and its token by *relationship fixup*.

Comment: Actually OP setup **is** one to one (one :) of the EF Core improvements). It's a FK with Unique constraint. But of course you are right for the rest.

Comment: That is exactly what I am now doing (using include), but this makes using repository and unit of work pattern almost impossible in case you want load different numbers of navigation properties each time (e.g. some times no nav prop,, some times 1, another time 4, and so forth), in that case I found no method to write any generic useful repository for that case... I hope that the support lazy loading again soon...

btw, what is this Dumb() function?

Comment: @Ivan I tried with the `UserId` field. I saw differences with EF6, but didn't realize it actually behaved as 1:1. Even then, I think I would like to have the database schema itself enforce it too (as much as possible, that is). By the way, I'm starting to get quite pleased with ef-core lately.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Dump is from Linqpad. I removed it. About your concerns, this is what I keep saying about architecture: architecture should be *helpful*. I've seen too many UoW/Repository implementations that have become a strait-jacket. Usually it means that a repository has become responsible for one entity and each operation involving multiple entities (object graphs) raises the responsibility question. Same for reading. With EF you *should* be able to read rich object graphs from the database. If the architecture doesn't allow it, modify it, or ditch it altogether.

Comment: With your repositories, it may be possible to add methods with parameters for properties to be `Include`d.

Comment: @GertArnold Any example for Include parameter? I thought about it with no useful idea in my mind.