# EF Core load nested navigation properties without .load()?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327515/ef-core-returns-null-relations-untill-direct-access/42329028#42329028) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596608/no-nested-results-in-entity-framework-core) for the same basic question - this question takes it one step further.

So I am using DB first (MySql, Pomelo EFCore framework) to a custom user database with a user table, roles table, and userroles (join) table in a .NET Core project. I have set up my EF classes to handle Many to many relationships as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#other-relationship-patterns):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{   
//user and roles table omitted for brevity 

    modelBuilder.Entity<Userroles>(entity =>
    {
         entity.HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId });

          entity.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
              .WithMany(u => u.UserRoles)
              .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);

          entity.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
              .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
              .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);
        });
    }
```

And my corresponding classes are these:

```
public partial class Users
{
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        //lots of properties

        public List<Userroles> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Roles
{
        [Key]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public List<Userroles> UserRoles { get; set; }

}

public partial class Userroles
{
        [ForeignKey("Users")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public Users User { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Roles")]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public Roles Role { get; set; }
}
```

The problem initially occurs when I try to load a user with their roles.

Doing this returns the user with a list of attached userroles, but the Role property in each userrole is null:

```
var user = db.Users.Where(user => user.Sid == userName).Include(u => u.UserRoles).FirstOrDefault()
```

If I call `db.Roles.Load();` prior to executing the above, then userroles are correctly populated with their Role property.

So the question is - is this the best way to accomplish loading of many to many navigation properties? Or is there a better way where I don't have to call `db.Roles.Load();` first?

EDIT:
Here's the [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) on loading related data. I have tried a few different ways of working with the .ThenInclude(x => x.whatever), without success. For example, I've tried this:

```
var user = db.Users.Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(u => u.Select(ur => ur.Role)).Where(user => user.Sid == userName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Which throws:

> System.ArgumentException: The property expression 'u => {from
>   Userroles ur in u select [ur].Role}' is not valid. The expression
>   should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.

What I'm attempting to do is include the List from userRoles for the given user.

Comment: Define "_can't seem to get that to work correctly_"...

Comment: @Tseng, see update. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: btw you are not allowed to use `.Select` inside of `ThenInclude`. It is different than how `Include` worked in EF6

Comment: The argument of `ThenInclude` is the type of the element of the previous `Include` / `ThenInclude`. In your case, `Userroles`. So it should be `.ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role)`. See [Including Multiple Levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).